# OpenLayers vs. OpenLayers 3 adding MapServer Layers

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3, mapserver

I'm hoping the answer to this is quite simple and I just have something simple out of place.

In OpenLayers 1 I add a layer like this...

```
 msSection = new OpenLayers.Layer.MapServer("Section",
          MSBaseURL+"/MappingSection.map&",
          { layers: 'section', exceptions: "application/vnd.ogc.se_xml" },
          { isBaseLayer: false, opacity: 0.9 },
          { tileSize: new OpenLayers.Size(256, 256), buffer: 1 });
        msSection.setVisibility(false);
```

the map file looks like this...

```
MAP
IMAGETYPE      PNG24
CONFIG "PROJ_LIB" "C:/Program Files/MapServer/projlib/"
SIZE           256 256
FONTSET "D:/RCIS/Web/MapServerDlls/content/fontset.txt"
IMAGECOLOR     255 255 255
TRANSPARENT ON
PROJECTION 
    "init=epsg:4326"
END
LAYER
    NAME "section"
    TYPE POLYGON
    STATUS ON
    LABELCACHE ON 
    PROCESSING 'LABEL_NO_CLIP=1' 
    CONNECTIONTYPE PLUGIN
    PLUGIN "msplugin_mssql2008.dll"
    MAXGEOWIDTH .08
    CONNECTION "server=someserver,someport;uid=someuser;pwd=somepassword;Initial Catalog=NATIONALDB;Integrated Security=False"
    DATA "shape(geography),SECTION from NATIONALDB.sde.SECTION USING INDEX SECTION_SIDX USING UNIQUE SECTION_ID USING SRID=4269"
    LABELITEM    "SECTION"
    CLASS
        STYLE            
         OUTLINECOLOR 255 000 000
         WIDTH 3
        END
         LABEL
            COLOR 255 000 000
            TYPE TRUETYPE
            FONT Arial 
            SIZE 12
            ANTIALIAS TRUE
            POSITION CL
            PARTIALS FALSE
            #MINDISTANCE 300
            #BUFFER 15
        END
    END     
    PROJECTION 
         "init=epsg:4326"
    END
END

END
```

...and everything is happy and works...
I try to add this in OpenLayers 3...

```
var Section = new ol.layer.Tile({
            name: 'Section',
            source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=D:/RCIS/Web/Mapfiles/MappingSection.map&',
                params: { 'LAYERS': 'section' },
                serverType: 'mapserver'
            })
        });

        control.map.addLayer(Section);
```

...and it shows code 200 OK in chrome dev tools but does not work,
when I put one of the tiles returned into the address bar I get this error..

```
<ServiceException>
msWMSDispatch(): WMS server error. WMS request not enabled. Check     wms/ows_enable_request settings.
</ServiceException>
```

I'm completely confused by this, any help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OpenLayers.Layer.MapServer` uses the [MapServer CGI Controls](http://mapserver.org/cgi/controls.html#mapserver-cgi-controls) to do its requests, not WMS.  Since MapServer supports WMS, the CGI Controls are not used much anymore to draw map images with MapServer.

In OpenLayers 3, the format you're using is `ol.source.TileWMS`, which produces WMS requests.  If you inspect the request sent (see in your browser dev tool using the F12 key), you'll see that the requests sent to render the images are WMS requests, i.e. they do not use the MapServer CGI Controls.

What you need to do is change your mapfile to make it support WMS.  See how it's done here: http://mapserver.org/ogc/wms_server.html.  More specifically, look at the [Setup a Mapfile For your WMS](http://mapserver.org/ogc/wms_server.html#setup-a-mapfile-for-your-wms) section.

Comment: Thank you!!  I've been battling this for too long!!